# Sticky footer ads for AMP in footer not working in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ads, amp-html

I'm trying to enable sticky footer ads on my AMP pages in WordPress using the Ad Inserter plugin. The in-page ads are working fine on AMP but not the sticky footer or the leaderboard (top of page).

Attached is a screenshot. Are there missing configurations?

I am using GeneratePress Premium theme and WooCommerce.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the official AMP plugin? if yes please create a new support topic on support forums https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/amp/#new-topic-0

Comment: @mark-marino : did you get any solution ?